# VirtualBox can't open Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04 host

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, windows-7

I downloaded a Windows 7 ISO, created the VM for it , but I'm getting the following error:

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for both all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)

Result Code-NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component-ConsoleWrap
Interface-IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go into your BIOS settings and enable VT (virtualization).

Check following link for more info http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/